# %x formating directive when passed characters

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
printf("argv[1] = %s\n", argv[1]);
printf("*argv[2] = %x\n", *argv[2]);
}

./commandline 123 abc
```

Can someone explain to me what is printed by the third printf statement? And explain what the line of code is doing - I'm having trouble understanding.

Thank you.

EDIT: Sorry, my question wasn't very clear - I understand that it's a format directive but I'm confused about what the acutal output would be. You're passing a pointer to the address of the first character - so how does the program print a hex value from a character?

Comment: Did you try it? What output did you get?

Comment: This is bad code.....without bound checking.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a question from a past exam.

Comment: What is unclear about the documentation of `printf`? What did you expect? What happened? We are not a "explain this code" site.

Comment: I'm sorry - I did search several times on google looking for the answer. We haven't really talked about documentation for functions but that would have been a good place to start. We were just introduced to C briefly (first year compsci student) and neither our course material or textbook explained this.

Will check the documentation first in future.

Comment: Can you please tell me where I can find the documentation? Nothing popped up on Google. What am I looking for exactly?

Comment: For Linux: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_2.html and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_3.html, for Windows/VC: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/634ca0c2.aspx

Comment: "Can you please tell me where I can find the documentation? Nothing popped up on Google." - Work on your search capabilities. You seriously tell "printf" does not show anything useful? Advice: if you lie, don't do it that obvious. For the rest: don't learn C by obscure youtube videos; get a good book.

Comment: The output will completely depend on the character coding in use, so there's not much we can portably say about it...

Answer (score 2):

In third `printf`, `argv[2]` points to the second command line argument after the name of the program.  In this case it is "abc".

So `*argv[2]` dereferences that pointer to point to the first character in the string which is 'a'.  This syntax is the same as `argv[2][0]`.

The `%x` format specifier says to print its argument in hexadecimal format.  It's argument is `*argv[2]` which is 'a'.  Assuming ASCII encoding, the ASCII value for this character is 97 decimal or 61 hex.

So the third `printf` outputs "61".

Answer (score 0):

`%x` prints the hexadecimal representation of an unsigned integer. In this case the first character from `argv[2]` argument.

So if you pass a letter 'a' as your argument, the print output should be the hexadecimal representation of that character, e.g. "61" if ASCII encoding. And because you are printing only the first character you will see the same "61" printed even if your command line argument would be "abc".

Link to the reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: Right, so the character is interpreted as an ascii value and this value in binary is printed as a hex number?

Comment: Yes, so if you pass a letter 'a' as your argument, the output should be 61. And because you are printing only the first character you will see same 61 printed even if your command line argument would be "abcd"

Comment: "*prints the value of unsigned hexadecimal integer*" should read: "prints the value of an unsigned integer hexadecimal format".

Comment: The fist sentence is wrong and contains assumptions not guaranteed. And even if we assume ASCII encoding, `a` is not `61`.

Answer (score -1):

`argv` is the sequence of command line arguments:

```
argv[0] == "./commandline" 
argv[1] == "123" 
argv[2] == "abc"
```

Each argument is a string (a zero-terminated array of `char`).

`*argv[2]` is equivalent to `argv[2][0]` - it evaluates to the first character of `argv[2]`, which is `'a'` (ASCII 97).

The type of the expression `*argv[2]` is `char` - since `printf` is a variadic function, the type of the expression is "promoted" from `char` to `int`.

The `%x` conversion specifier takes an `unsigned int` argument and formats the output as a hexadecimal integer; thus, that ASCII value of 97 is treated as an `unsigned int` and the output is the hexadecimal equivalent - `0x61`.

Comment: ""that ASCII value of 97 is treated as an unsigned int" - Passing an `int ` where an `unsigned int` is expected invokes UB. For the sake of simplicity, we might ignore the character codes are not necessarily ASCII encoded here.